# NoSuchMethodError WebUtils.isValidOrigin Spring websocket

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Here is my setup for a simple websocket controller in spring:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myHandler")
public class MyHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        String reply = "Hello there!!!!!!!!";
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(reply));
    }   
}
```

mcv-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<websocket:handlers allowed-origins="http://localhost">
    <websocket:mapping path="/myHandler" handler="myHandler"/>
    <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
    </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
</websocket:handlers>

<bean id="myHandler" class="com.aexp.socket.MyHandler"/>
```

I have updated all the jar files to correct versions
but I am getting following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException: Uncaught failure for request http://localhost:8080/Websocket/myHandler; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.isValidOrigin(Lorg/springframework/http/HttpRequest;Ljava/util/Collection;)Z

root cause

org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException: Uncaught failure for request http://localhost:8080/Websocket/myHandler; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.isValidOrigin(Lorg/springframework/http/HttpRequest;Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.java:135)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

And when I am trying to create WebSocket object in JS I get following:

```
(Opcode -1)
```

This is the first time I am trying to use WebSockets so not sure what I am missing. Can someone point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your .xml configuration as follows:

```
<websocket:handlers allowed-origins="http://localhost">
  <websocket:mapping path="/myHandler" handler="myHandler"/>
  <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
  <websocket:sockjs/>
</websocket:handshake-interceptors>
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "spring-web" dependency.
Add the following to your pom:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you probably need to run the "clean" goal, and rebuild the project.